# Android Studio android-maven not found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have checked out the source for the MyExpenses app from [github](https://github.com/mtotschnig/MyExpenses) and I checked out all dependencies, but for some reason I can't compile the app from within the studio, I can compile it successfully through command line using

```
java -Dorg.gradle.appname=gradlew -classpath /home/mfarag/Personal/Technical/JAVA/Android/Projects/MyExpenses/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain build
```

but when I compile it from the studio I get the error

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:myExpenses:assembleDebug]
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.compileSdkVersion is missing!
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:80)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.groovy:462)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.access$2(BasePlugin.groovy)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:386)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:278)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:504)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluationDependsOn(AbstractProject.java:562)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluationDependsOn(AbstractProject.java:554)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.ensureConfigured(DependencyManager.java:641)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencyForConfig(DependencyManager.java:232)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencies(DependencyManager.java:133)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.resolveDependencies(TaskManager.groovy:272)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$8.call(VariantManager.java:591)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$8.call(VariantManager.java:588)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:48)
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$record.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.groovy:69)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantData(VariantManager.java:587)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantDataForProductFlavors(VariantManager.java:690)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.populateVariantDataList(VariantManager.java:452)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:271)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createAndroidTasks_closure15.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:448)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createAndroidTasks_closure15.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:278)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders$2.call(SpanRecorders.groovy:52)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:189)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.groovy:54)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.groovy:447)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13_closure17.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:388)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13_closure17.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:278)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders$2.call(SpanRecorders.groovy:52)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:189)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.groovy:54)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:387)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:278)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:504)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:83)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:83)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:76)
    at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(CommandLineTaskParser.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$100(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$100(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.select(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
/home/mfarag/Personal/Technical/JAVA/Android/Projects/MyExpenses/MPAndroidChart/MPChartLib/build.gradle
Error:(2, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':MPAndroidChart:MPChartLib'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'android-maven']
   > Plugin with id 'android-maven' not found.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 9.764 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
```

Please advise